# Have Laravel model return an json alias

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a Laravel 6.x backend app (with AngularJS frontend) and have model return a `credentials` collection - I have a single json column called 'properties' which has the following json structure:

{"lastname": "Jones", "nickname": "DJones", "firstname": "Dan", "profilepicture": null}

This payload gets returned in a controller similar to this :

```
            $authResponsePayload = [
                'access_token' => $token,
                'credentials' => array_merge(
                    json_decode($credential->properties, true)
                ),
            ];
```

Is it possible to have some form of alias within the Model itself so `profilepicture` is returned as `picture` rather than `profilepicture` in a nice "laravel way"?

Comment: You can use `casts` of Laravel eloquent which takes care of JSON encoding and Decoding. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: You could use API resources to map the property names. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources